# How can I print German character

Tags: python, decode, encode

When I tried to print German in python, it's always garbled.
How can I print genuine German characters?

```
>print(org_discription)
Katts�ng Rund, mjuk artikel, enligt uppgift avsedd f�r katter, tillverkad av dukvara av trik� best�ende av 100 % polyester. .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing the following line at the beginning of the code file should fix the German characters:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
```

Source: https://www.python-forum.de/viewtopic.php?t=5095

PS: However that line doesn't look German. There might be some characters that require a different encoding, which is mentioned inside the link